# I need to POST xml list to an external website with receiving API

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Is there a way to use a POST to directly send a list from sharepoint to an external website with API set up to grab xml files?

This is my first time using sharepoint and we need to send a list on a daily timer to an external website. They have been entering it in manually, but want an automated connection straight between sharepoint and that external site. However, I can not find any information on this.

Any help would be very helpful as there seems to be nothing out there on this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint out-of-the-box doesn't have a mechanism to send data directly from a list to some external location.  You are going to have to do some custom coding.  Regardless of the timer mechanism you choose (console app via Windows timer, custom SharePoint Timer Job, etc.) your code is going to need to act as a client to get your SharePoint data as XML, hold it, and then act as client to your external web site and post it to that site.